R - Adding manifest exogenous variable to SEM leads to error
I am new to SEM, and some help would be very appreciated.
I want to specify a model with one latent endogenous variable (indicators are all ordinal), five latent exogenous variables (indicators are all ordina), and a manifest exogenous variable (continuous). Something like this:
Factor.A =~ a1 + a2 + a3
Factor.B =~ b1 + b2 + b3 + b4
Factor.C =~ c1 + c2 + c3
Factor.D =~ d1 + d2 + d3
Factor.E =~ e1 + e2 + e3
Factor.F =~ f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 + f5 + f6
Factor.F ~ Factor.A + Factor.B + Factor.C + Factor.D + Factor.E + pre_k

Running this code leads to the following error:
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn: length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
Purely by chance, I found that if I set any of the latent factors' covariance with pre_k (the manifest exogenous variable) to 0, the code runs without error. Please help me figure out what is going on.
